# Open context menu by click on the whole line in listbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp, listbox

In my code I have:

```
    <ListBox Name="Playlists_ListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,2" >
                    <Grid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu Name="cm"  StaysOpen="true" >
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <TextBlock Name="Name" Text="{Binding Title}"  Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

When I want now open context menu, I must click only on TextBlock. How can I do it to open context menu by click on any part of listbox item - one line in listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Context menu for your ListBox so that you'll get context menu wherever you click on Listbox

```
  <ListBox Name="Playlists_ListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,2" >
                    <TextBlock Name="Name" Text="{Binding Title}"  Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu StaysOpen="True">
                <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
            </ContextMenu>
         </ListBox.ContextMenu>
  </ListBox>
```